# eclipse error about builing project archive

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven

I am trying to setup an empty project by maven for using WELD CDI and JSF. Every thing was OK until I have a strange error message from eclipse when I am trying to clean and rebuild:

[image]

I have no idea which file it is trying to locate. is it web.xml or any other descriptor file?
any body knows how I can fix this problem?

Comment: see this http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/m2eclipse-eclipse-galileo-td139191.html

Comment: I am using eclipse Juno, it is about the bug in  galileo

Comment: thanks for your comment, there was a hint which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was jboss tools plugin, I don't know why.
My problem is solved by removing Jboss tools plugin from my eclipse Juno.